# failed to build aosp. says subcommand failed

Tags: android, android-source

I've been struggling, googleing and recreating the entire virtual machine for 2 weeks still but can't figure out...

I don't think I missed any part from the instruction provided by aosp. 
Can someone please help me to solve the issue I got below? I was running `make -j8` then got this

```
Starting build with ninja
ninja: Entering directory `.'
[  0% 1/34696] Yacc: aidl <= system/tools/aidl/aidl_language_y.yy
FAILED: /bin/bash -c "prebuilts/misc/linux-x86/bison/bison -d  --defines=out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libaidl-common_intermediates/aidl_language_y.h -o out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libaidl-common_intermediates/aidl_language_y.cpp system/tools/aidl/aidl_language_y.yy"
/bin/bash: prebuilts/misc/linux-x86/bison/bison: No such file or directory
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
build/core/ninja.mk:148: recipe for target 'ninja_wrapper' failed
make: *** [ninja_wrapper] Error 1
```

Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 11):

I had the same error. The file was there as you mentioned in comment. The reason was bison is a 32-bit binary and my ubuntu is 64bit.
I had to install libc6:i386,libncurses5:i386,libstdc++6:i386.

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```

You can find more detailed info in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133389/no-such-file-or-directory-but-the-file-exists).

Comment: above problem solved. now getting another error

flex-2.5.39: loadlocale.c:130: _nl_intern_locale_data: Assertion `cnt < (sizeof (_nl_value_type_LC_TIME) / sizeof (_nl_value_type_LC_TIME[0]))' failed.

Answer (score 1):

```
 sudo apt-get install bison
```

Try this. It will fix your issue.

Comment: yea, i did this too. i also did `ls prebuilts/misc/linux-x86/bison` and found bison is actually there. I can also invoke bison from the command line

Comment: Not sure exactly what my problem was, but your solution actually solved my issue. Downvoters should probably provide an explanation when voting.

Comment: work for me !Thk you !

Comment: this did work for me this way..

used apt instead of apt-get

sudo apt install bison

and then 

linked 

'sudo ln /usr/bin/bison  prebuilts/misc/linux-x86/bison/bison'